# How do I subscribe to an event in a class from another static class?

Tags: c#, events

What's wrong in this case?
When  try to subscribe on event I have a CS0407:'return-type method' has the wrong return type;
**skeleton.OnDeath += Beholder.AddListener;**

but I can't figure out where the error is.
Action return void. And param in signature is int.
In AddListener - too.

```cs
namespace Tasks7 {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            Skeleton skeleton = new Skeleton();
            skeleton.OnDeath += Beholder.AddListener;
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Skeleton {
        public static int lastID = 0;
        public int id = 0;
        public delegate Action<int> Death (int id);
        public event Death OnDeath;
        public Skeleton() {
            this.id = lastID++;
        }
        public void Kill() {
            OnDeath?.Invoke(this.id);
        }
    }

    static class Beholder {
        public static void AddListener(int id) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{id} ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the signature of your delegate and listener method don't match.

The delegate signature is

```cs
Action<int> Death(int id);
```

while the listener function's signature is

```cs
void AddListener(int id)
```

To add `AddListener` to the `OnDeath` event, it would have to return an `Action<int>`.

But I suspect what's really happening is that you misunderstand the delegate declaration syntax.

```cs
public delegate Action<int> Death(int id);
```

This declares a new delegate type that takes a single integer argument and returns an `Action<int>`. To make it compatible with the `AddListener` method, just change the return type from `Action<int>` to `void`.

---

Note: `Action<int>` itself is already a delegate type, so you could scrap the `Death` delegate altogether and instead use `Action<int>` in the event handler declaration like this:

```cs
public event Action<int> OnDeath;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand how to work with built-in delegates.